# why i cant merge two list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

i'm reading anotonio leava book about kotlin 
there is a function named "merge" it can merge two list with each other
this is a code that author write in his book:

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)

val anotherlist = listOf(7,8,9,10,11,12)

assertEquals(listOf(8,10,12,14,16,18),list.merge(anotherlist){it1,it2 - > it1+it2})
```

it means merge is plusing two list
but when i write code myself
my idea intelij doesnt know the func name
and it doesnt work 
can you help me
sorry because of my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` is neither a member function of `List`, nor does the kotlin standard library provide an extension function. But you can define one by your own (and I suspect, that's what the author did)

```
fun <E> List<E>.merge(anotherlist: List<E>, operation: (E, E) -> E): List<E> {
    // you probably want to check cardinalities of the two lists
    return indices.map { operation(this[it], anotherlist[it]) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the use of map

```
   val x: List<Int> = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    val y: List<Int> = listOf(2,3,4,5,6,7)
    val sums = (x.indices).map { x[it] + y[it] }
```

output

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Comment: Also, you can use union to combine two lists like 

ListUtils.union(list1, list2)

Comment: i want to plus two element , same indexed, of two list and reurn another list like that::     list1= [1,2,3]     list2=[5,6,7]     returned list = [6,8,10]   and how can i use "merge" why merge doesnt work?

Comment: Got your point, See my edited answer, It will work for you

Comment: thank you now it works but i still have this question that is merge wrong? why it doesnt work and if it doesnt work why antonio leavia wrote it in his book? thank uou for your help

Comment: @bardianasiri I haven't read the book, but maybe this person declared his own `merge` function in the book at some previous point, you should double check.

Comment: thanks ! it was my first question in stackoverflow.com

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow, it would be great if you accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of map you can use [zip](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) function

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val list1 = listOf(4, 5, 6)
    val list2 = listOf(1, 2, 3)

    val result = list1.zip(list2) { e1, e2 -> e1 + e2 }
    println(result) // prints [5, 7, 9]
}
```